# AOSP build with make -j16 completes without building the latest code

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP code. I see that whenever I make some changes in the module , its not always reflected in the system.img or ramdisk.img. The make fails to detect the changes in source code and picks up the old binary or old executable and creates system.img using that binary or executable.

I have to build the source code twice or thrice using make -j16 or delete the intermediate files to get it actually reflected. Any reason, why this is the case ? Any solution to make sure it will work without removing intermediates and in one go?

Regards,

Sameer Joshi

Comment: What module are you trying to update?

Answer (score 0):

use these commands before running  *make -j16*

```
$ make installclean
$ make clobber
```

[Clobber](https://source.android.com/source/running.html)

> Cleaning up To ensure the newly installed binaries are properly taken
> into account after being extracted, delete the existing output of any
> previous build ..

This might not necessarily solve your problem. Give it a go.

Comment: This will of course work. I wanted to know if it can be done wihout clean.